# Particles Don't Show A Material

Tags: materials, particles

Hi I am trying to make a fire simulation with embers. For the embers, I created a sphere and put a material on it that changes color depending on how fast the embers are going. The color should go from yellow to orange (which is the color the original sphere is), but for some reason the particles turn out white. I thought it might be that I had the emission too high, but eventually I disconnected the material from the sphere entirely, but the particles still turn out white. No matter what I do, it doesn't change. Anyone know what could be happening?

Here's a picture (with the actual sphere in the back):

[image]

Comment: I am sure you did this but just double check you picked the orange sphere as your object in the particles tab.

Comment: You can always upload your blend file and I can take a look http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your particles or simulation or your textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I actually had two spheres in the project, I had the wrong one selected. Thanks!